# domain and range of a transformed function

Tags: functions, transformation

This is the original function; y=f(x) with a domain of -3<_ x <_ 3 and a range of 0 <_ y <_ 3.

Now I was asked to find the range and domain of y=f(x-2).

So I said -3<_ x <_ 3 and 1<_ y <_ 5.

But the answer was -1<_ x <_ 5 and 0 <_ y <_ 3.

I don't get it. Am I supposed to keep the same range, not the domain? Is that what it is? Why is my answer wrong?

Comment: Formatting tips here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264.

Comment: Why did you say that range is $1\leq y \leq 5$ ?

Comment: @Mathematics Because that is what I get when I put in -3<_ x <_ 3  into  y=f(x-2). I thought I had to keep the domain the same, because domain is basically Xs that I am supposed to put in. I do not understand the goal of this transformation. Is the goal putting in the Xs into the transformed function that will result in the same range?

Answer (score 1):

The domain is the set of numbers you plug into $f$. Here, the number you plug into $f$ needs to be between $-3$ and $3$. Since the number you're plugging into $f$ is $x-2$, this means you need $-3 \le x-2 \le 3$, which is equivalent to $-1 \le x \le 5$.

The range is the set of values that the function $f$ takes; since $f(x-2)$ is simply a value of $f$ for each input $x$, the range of the new function is the same as the range of the old function.

Comment: Great explanation !!

Comment: Ok. I registered. I still don't get it. Why doesn't domain stay the same? Why can't I keep it the same and just change the range? How is it invalid?

Comment: Is my main goal keeping the range the same?

Answer (score 1):

**Key Point:** For domain we need condition on $x$ and for range we need condition on $y$.

Given that domain of $f(x)$ is $-3 \leq x \leq 3$, it means whatever is written in  place of '$?$' in $f(?)$ should lie between $-3$ and and $3$

Now if I write $x-2$ in place of '$?$', then I get

$$-3 \leq x-2 \leq3$$

But for domain we need condition of on x, hence add $2$ in inequality, which gives

$$-3+2 \leq x-2+2 \leq3+2$$

$$-1 \leq x\leq5$$ which is the required domain.

Is it clear now?

Comment: It...kind of is. But what about with 1/6f(x+17)? It has this 1/6. Does my domain have to be −3≤x+2≤3 or −3≤1/6(x+2)≤3?

Comment: In $f(?)$,what is written in place of '$?$' in $\frac{1}{6} f(x+17)$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: It means that $-3 \leq x+17 \leq 3$, For domain only see what is written inside $f()$

Comment: Oh.............Now it is so clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Mathematics $+1$ for great explanation.